# Upload to S3 - An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website build in C# and MVC4 where users can upload large files which are in turn sent to Amazon S3.

It is intermittent but I keep getting the following error:

**"An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 54.231.236.12:443"**

I am currently using an InputStream as the PutObject for S3. Does anyone have any recommendations as to why the PutObject would be failing on these larger files?

Below is the code that I am using to send the HttpPostedFileBase to Amazon:

```
 HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;

            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Amazon_Access_Key"];
                string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Amazon_Secret_Key"];


                AmazonS3Client client;

                var filePath = UserID + "/" + hpf.FileName;

                client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest1);

                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

                request.BucketName = "MyBucket";
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                request.Key = filePath;
                request.InputStream = hpf.InputStream;
                client.PutObject(request);
            }
                return Json(new {message = "chunk uploaded", name = name});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the mean issue upon uploading your large file into S3 but from the error message you posted it seems that you were trying to upload one big file in one shut. I suggest that you should upload your large file into chunks. I found some links that could help to achieve it.

- [Streaming](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html)
- [Multi part Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMPDotNetAPI.html)
- [Multi part Concept](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/)
- [Multi part API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html)
- [Forum about S3 Chucking](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=561616)

Hopefully this links could help you!